# "Emulate" 256 colors in PuTTY terminal

Tags: linux, vim, putty, colors

At my job, I ssh into a development server everyday.  I usually use exceed XStart to ssh in, but I downloaded PuTTY to see if I could do anything that I couldn't do with XStart.

I spend almost the entire day looking at the regular white background/black text terminal.  The `TERM` variable in the server is set to `vt100`, and as far as I know, it's an eight-color display.

I was wondering if there was a way to have PuTTY emulate a 256 color terminal.  I would really like some syntax highlighting in Vim, and the built-in ones are just awful.  I've tried `vim -T xterm-256color`, and that only seems to let me use the default color schemes.

I also tried setting `t_Co=256`, but that doesn't work either.

If it helps, the dev server is a Red Hat 6 box.

Answer (score 56):

### 1. Configure Putty

In *Settings > Windows > Colours* there is a check box for "Allow terminal to use xterm 256-colour mode".

### 2. Let the app know

You'll probably have to change *Settings -> Connection > Data > Terminal-type* string to:

`xterm-256color`

---

if your server has a terminfo entry for `putty-256color`, typically in `/usr/share/terminfo/p/putty-256color`, you can set Putty's Terminal-Type to `putty-256color` instead.

The main thing here is to make the server use an available Terminfo entry that most closely matches the way Putty is configured.

---

See also http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/terminfo.html

Comment: I have just verified that I can get 256 colors in Vim with PuTTY when that option is enabled. PuTTY seems to set the TERM to "xterm" automatically for me; you may still need to manually do ":set t_Co=256" within Vim.

Comment: I tried the Allow xterm 256-color mode, and that hasn't done anything.  I also changed the terminal string to xterm-color, that also did nothing.

Comment: @bahamat I tried that too, that didn't work

Comment: @Tom: All other systems that I've used use xterm-256color. If putty doesn't do anything with that I'm not sure anything else can be done. Check this page: [http://www.frexx.de/xterm-256-notes/](http://www.frexx.de/xterm-256-notes/) and try the `256colors2.pl` script to determine for sure wether or not it's working.

Comment: For nice colors in vim, it's important to also install the [CSApprox](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390) plugin.

Comment: Thanks! I did some screen shots: http://ceving.blogspot.de/2014/10/emacs-with-256-colors-in-screen-and.html

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick `xterm-256color` was the key in Putty that I have been missing all these years! So awesome. And thanks Heptite for that comment about `t_Co=256` too.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `putty-256color`? https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/putty-configuration/

Answer (score 10):

I recommend the `putty-256color` terminal type instead of `xterm-256color`, if the system you're logging in to includes the appropriate `terminfo` file (or if you have permissions to install the `terminfo` file there). The `putty`/`putty-256color` TERM has better support for some keys (e.g. F1-F4).

Comment: Setting `putty-256color` without a `~/.terminfo` file will result with the following when using certain programs, such as nano: `Error opening terminal: putty-256color.`

Comment: That's why I mentioned that the terminfo file should be already present on the system, or installed locally.

Comment: This added the terminfo files I needed: apt-get install ncurses-term

Comment: I agree with using `putty-256color`.  I tried using `xterm-256color` in the Terminal-type string.  (Tested in KiTTY)  It seemed ok at first but when I started KiTTY and got back into screen, it resized the window to 80 columns.  `putty-256color` does not have this problem and the colors work.