# Putty shows prompt with no color, but Linux SSH can

Tags: ssh, putty, colors

In Windows Putty, the command line prompt "gqqnbig@n2-16g" is not in color. However if I run `ls`, it gives me color.

However, if I go to Ubuntu and run the terminal, where I run ssh and connect to the same server, Ubuntu terminal shows the colorful command line prompt.

How do I fix Putty so that it shows the same color as Ubuntu terminal?

Comment: Do outputs of `echo "$TERM"` differ between the two cases? What are they?

Comment: `ls --color=never`

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Ubuntu terminal outputs "xterm-256color", while Putty outputs "xterm".

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/436928/432690) should help you. Let PuTTY use `xterm-256color` as well. If it works then please answer your own question. Somewhere in your startup scripts `PS1` depends on `$TERM`. Changing this behavior may be an alternative solution.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski it works! Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Kamil Maciorowski's suggestion works. In Putty, change Settings -> Connection > Data > Terminal-type string to:

xterm-256color